# If $a,b\in \mathbb D$ then $a+b\in \mathbb D$ and $a-b\in \mathbb D$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $O$ and $I$ are any two points in the plane consider a coordinate system such that the interval $OI$ coincides with the unit interval on the x-axis. Let $\mathbb D$ be the set of real numbers such that $a\in \mathbb D$ iff the point $(a,0)$ is constructible from {$O,I$}.
>
> 1. If $a,b\in \mathbb D$ then $a+b\in \mathbb D$ and $a-b\in \mathbb D$.
> 2. If $a,b \in \mathbb D$ then $ab\in \mathbb D$.

I do not entirely understand the concept of constructible numbers? I know that we use a straightedge and a protractor and if the point can be made with these items then it's constructible, however, I do not see how this translates to operations?

Answer (score 0):

The set $\Bbb{D}$ is a subset of the real numbers, so we can add, subtract and multiply any pair of them. The point of the question is to show that the sum, difference and product of two constructible numbers is again constructible. For example; if $a$ and $b$ are constructible then $a+b$ is constructible because the point $(a+b,0)$ is one of the intersection points of the circle of radius $a$ centered at $b$ and the $x$-axis. Of course you need to prove that this circle is constructible.

Similarly, you need to give constructions of the points $(a-b,0)$ and $(ab,0)$.

Comment: I have taken the approach: let OI (which I will refer to as L for convenience) =(0,1) then we have some points P=(a,0) and Q=(b,1). Q is constructible by a horizontal line through L and a vertical line through (b,0). The line through Q parallel to LP intersects the x-axis at some point (a+b,0). Does this seem correct?

Comment: $OI$ is an interval and $(0,1)$ is a point. How can they be equal? Your construction seems to work, assuming you are able to construct horizontal and vertical lines through a point, and lines through a point parallel to a given line.

Comment: Oh wow I totally glazed over that. If I define some point $L=(0,1)$ on $OI$ do you believe the construction would still follow?

Comment: The point $L=(0,1)$ is not on $OI$. The coordinates in the plane are chosen such that $OI$ is the unit interval on the $x$-axis *as you wrote in the question yourself*.